# REST entity files initialization design

Tags: java, rest, maven, resteasy

I have REST server that needs to return  response object initialized to default values in some cases.

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response method() {
response = new Class1(); //Class2 obj2 composite object is created here in Class1.

return Response.ok(response).build();

}


public Class1 {

int var1;
String var2;
Class2 obj2;

public Class1() {
  var1=0;
  var2="";
  obj2= new Class2();
}

public Class2 getClass2() {
  return obj2;
}
```

}

Above Class1, Class2 present in the maven module which is also used by the REST clients.

In the client if I want to make a request that passes an instance of Class1 I have to write like this.

```
Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
Class2 obj2 = obj1.getClass2(); //Client must know the class1 constructor creates internal object. And should not create new Class2 explicitly.

obj2.setX(5);
obj2.setY(6);
```

Another approach I'm thinking of is to initialize class members at class level and not to create composite objects in constructor. Have a init() method that can be invoked to create composite objects.

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response method() {
    response = new Class1();
    //want to send empty response
    response.init(); // creates all internal objects

    return Response.ok(response).build();

    }
```

your suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: *"return an empty response initialized to default values"* If the response is empty, how can it have default values? Empty mean nothing there, so there are no "values" at all, so nothing to specify anything "default".

Comment: I guess you know the difference between nothing(null) and empty. If there is nothing then how client initialize/parse a value?

Comment: To avoid passing null I want to pass the response with default values. Just removed word empty in it. Sorry.

Comment: what value do you get from exposing Class2? Can you make it private and use delegation methods in Class1 instead? e.g. Class1.setX() calls Class2.setX()

Comment: Getters and setters are present in all classes for it's private member variables. @codebrane getClass2() gives you the new instance created in class1 constructor.